# App running on simulator + physical device suddenly have black screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Running Xcode 9.4.1 with Swift 4, app suddenly gets stuck on a black screen when it starts up on any View Controller. Nothing crashes (no breakpoints either), and when the signup screen opens, the view is visible in the background while the Push Notification permission window appears. After the window is accepted, the screen returns to black.

App Delegate runs with no problems, and the logs appear to be normal, as if the views were loading correctly.

I attempted cleaning build folder, deleting Derived Data, reseting simulator, and restarted the phone and Xcode with no luck. Device is an iPhone 6, simulators tested on various iPhones.

Edit: It appears the app works when this function is deleted in the App Delegate.

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {        
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    if application.applicationIconBadgeNumber > 0 {
        let startVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = startVC
        appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    }

}
```

Comment: show code of push notification

Comment: Just updated the question

Comment: on other device is it working? What if 'applicationIconBadgeNumber == 0'

Comment: Not sure why, but the app works as normal when I delete applicationDidBecomeActive function, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the following line:

```
 appDelegate.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
```

What you are doing is you are setting the new window object with the frame to the AppDelegate's key window.

You should update your code to:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    if application.applicationIconBadgeNumber > 0 {

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let startVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = startVC
        appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    }

}
```

Try and share the results.